# Store logon data for different types of systems, and apply to GDPR

Tags: security, password-manager

As a software developing company, we have a lot of logon data for different types of systems.
This can be a simple username/password combination for a website, but also FTP accounts, database accounts, RDP accounts, SSH accounts, enryptions keys, you name it.

Currently, this data is just stored in a big Excel file. Of course, everyone who can access this file, can see everything.

"The best" solution for now, I guess, would be some software were you can store the information in. And based on AD rights, you can allow someone to see this information or not. Some kind of password vault.

We looked at LastPass, but this is not realy what I want. Because we have to store different types of account information. And LastPass is mostly oriented on username/password combinations for websites.

I guess there are a lot of other EU companies with the same struggle, but I cannot find good information about it on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

KeePass can store not only username/password tokens, but many other things.

See https://keepass.info/features.html :

> You can attach files to password entries (useful to store PGP signature files in KeePass for example).
>
> [2.x] KeePass has a powerful internal viewer/editor for text files, images and documents. You don't even need to export attached files to view/edit them!

It is open source, localized and available on multiple platforms.

You can define multiple "databases" storing different groups of secrets, and you then rely on your underlying OS to define who can access what.